# Aerospike cluster not clean available blocks

Tags: aerospike

we use aerospike in our projects and caught strange problem. 
We have a 3 node cluster and after some node restarting it stop working.
 So, we make test to explain our problem

We make test cluster. 3 node, replication count  = 2

Here is our namespace config

```
namespace test{
replication-factor 2
memory-size 100M
high-water-memory-pct 90
high-water-disk-pct 90
stop-writes-pct 95
single-bin true
default-ttl 0
storage-engine device {
cold-start-empty true
file /tmp/test.dat
write-block-size 1M
}
```

We write 100Mb test data after that we have that situation

[image]
available pct equal about 66% and Disk Usage about 34%

All good :slight_smile:

But we stopped one node. After migration  we see that available pct =  49% and disk usage 50%

Return node to cluster and after migration we see that disk usage became previous about 32%, but **available pct on old nodes stay 49%**

[image]
Stop node one more time

available pct = 31%

Repeat one more time we get that situation
available pct = 0%

Our cluster crashed, Clients get AerospikeException: Error Code 8: Server memory error

So how we can clean available pct?

Comment: Please can you grep defrag-q in your log and post the results?

Comment: I believe you namespace is too small for the default post-write-queue. Try setting that to 0 in config and repeat test.

Comment: kporter likely nailed it. The default post write queue would be 256 x 1MB (write block size) per device. Blocks in the post write queue cannot be defragmented. Lowering it to 8 or something small should help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `defrag-q` is empty (and you can see whether it is from grepping the logs) then the issue is likely to be that your namespace is smaller than your post-write-queue.  Blocks on the `post-write-queue` are not eligible for defragmentation and so you would see `avail-pct` trending down with no defragmentation to reclaim the space.  By default the `post-write-queue` is 256 blocks and so in your case that would equate to 256Mb.  If your namespace is smaller than that you will see avail-pct continue to drop until you hit stop-writes.  You can reduce the size of the post-write-queue dynamically (i.e. no restart needed) using the following command, here I suggest 8 blocks:

```
asinfo -v 'set-config:context=namespace;id=<NAMESPACE>;post-write-queue=8'
```

If you are happy with this value you should amend your `aerospike.conf` to include it so that it persists after a node restart.